# The test code is ok, but after submitting it shows a memory leak

Tags: c

recently i do the home work , the result have no problem, but submit gitlab can dont pass.
it shows "memory leak". i have changed some code , it works .
Is it because I didn't use free() in function insert and print_lili().

The result after submit:

[image]

Here is my codes. i have many tried but no effect.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lili.h"

element_t* head = NULL;
//implement necessary functions here
element_t* end ;
unsigned int* insert_element(unsigned int value) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = (element_t*)malloc(sizeof(element_t));
        end = head;
        
    }
    element_t* node = (element_t*)malloc(sizeof(element_t));

    if (node != NULL) {
        node->data = value;
       // node->next = NULL;

        end->next = node;
        end = node;
        end->next = NULL;

        return &end->data;
        
    }
    else {
        perror("perror:malloc failed;");
        return NULL;
    }
}

unsigned int remove_element() {
    // delete first node
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("WARNING: nothing to remove, lili is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        element_t* temp = (element_t*)malloc(sizeof(element_t));
        temp = head->next;

        int nodeValue = temp->data;
        //printf("value: is %d\n", value);

        head->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = NULL;
        return nodeValue;

    }

}

void print_lili() {
    element_t* temp = head;
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("print lili:\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("print lili:");
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
            printf("%d ,", temp->data);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are developing on a LInux system, I suggest that you run you code under valgrind using the tool memcheck (valgrind --tool=memcheck ./your_program).  It will show you where you are leaking memory.  You may need to add a few flags (described in the output of valgrind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `remove_element` allocates some memory then immediately leaks it with the assignment on the next line. There is no reason for `remove_element` to allocate memory.

Change the code to be

```c
element_t* temp = head->next;
```